# How to create a toggle delay if div is visible/ active?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am looking for a way to create a delay on a class if another class is visible / active

In this example it takes 1s to toggle the class opacity so if '.about__section' is showing (has class 'show') for example, I want it to have 1s to fade out (finishing the animation) before '.work__section' starts to fade in.

I only want this delay to happen though if one of the other classes has the class 'show'

Any suggestions?

```js
$(".about").on("click", function() {
    
    $(".about__section").toggleClass("show");
    
    $(".work__section").removeClass("show");

});
  
  
$(".work").on("click", function() {
    
    $(".work__section").toggleClass("show");
    
    $(".about__section").removeClass("show");

});
```

```css
.about, .work {
cursor: pointer;
}

.about__section, .work__section {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
}

.about__section.show, .work__section.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="content">

  <li class="about">About</li>

  <li class="work">Work</li>

</ul>






<div class="about__section">



    <p>About:<br>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </p>
                
</div><!-- End of About Section -->


<div class="work__section">



    <p>work:<br>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </p>
                
</div><!-- End of About Section -->
```

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you want to do but is adding the transition on .about__section.show, .work__section.show helping? Like this:
.about__section.show, .work__section.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` to have this, its not nice looking solution, I think there might be a better way to do it with CSS, but here is a jQuery solution:

```js
$(".about").on("click", function () {
  if ($(".work__section").hasClass("show")) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $(".about__section").toggleClass("show");
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $(".about__section").toggleClass("show");
  }
  $(".work__section").removeClass("show");
});

$(".work").on("click", function () {
  if ($(".about__section").hasClass("show")) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $(".work__section").toggleClass("show");
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $(".work__section").toggleClass("show");
  }
  $(".about__section").removeClass("show");
});
```

```css
.about, .work {
cursor: pointer;
}

.about__section, .work__section {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
}

.about__section.show, .work__section.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="content">

  <li class="about">About</li>

  <li class="work">Work</li>

</ul>






<div class="about__section">



    <p>About:<br>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </p>
                
</div><!-- End of About Section -->


<div class="work__section">



    <p>work:<br>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </p>
                
</div><!-- End of About Section -->
```

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by 'not a nice looking solution'?
I changed the else statement from 'addclass' to 'toggleClass' and it works perfectly how I wanted it to

Comment: I said that because I believe there is a way to do it in CSS, I'm not expert in CSS animation, also for the `toggle()` I will switch it back.

Comment: Okay cool, I'm just trying to understand something - Is it preferable to do through css animation? Is there a downside to this method? Or is it just that it would be easier to write with css

Comment: hmmm, no come to think of it there is some tricks you can do but in your case it would make it complicated for a small part of the code, so I don't think its bad to have like this.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution would be to just add second parameter for delay. However, you can easily achieve it through CSS animation as well. You can implement the below solution if you want to do it through jQuery. Also, keep 1000 i.e. 1s or remove it from wherever you don't want the delay.

```
$(".about").on("click", function() {

    $(".about__section").toggleClass("show", 1000);

    $(".work__section").removeClass("show", 1000);

});


$(".work").on("click", function() {

    $(".work__section").toggleClass("show", 1000);

    $(".about__section").removeClass("show", 1000);

});
```